# trigger alarm when current time equals to sunrise time even application in background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my application I am using a CLLocation manager to find out the current location. And according to the current location I want to get sunrise and sunset times in my location.

For example: 
if current location is San Francisco, then sunrise time and sunset time are the ones in San Francisco. Till this point I succeeded.
But I want to trigger an alarm everyday if current time equals sunrise time even when my application is in background.

I have searched many ways, but not even one satisfied me. I am new to iOS development.

applicationDidEnterBackground method runs for some time before terminating application.

Comment: It is not really possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9621425/908621 for a partial answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to setup a background location mode in the plist to make it respond on location updates even in backround. Then in location updated callback get the time of sunset and shcedule local notification on that time.

Also it's beter to manage notifications and disable inappropriate ones (changed location = > new notification).

**UPDATE:**
In your particular situation there is no need in continuous stream of location data, significant location changes tracking would be fine. This approach does not require background location mode requested in plist and won't drain battery with the speed of light. You may find info here : [- (void)startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges).
Note that even with background location mode app is not running continuously in background, it's only invoked to execute location update callbacks.

So at first you:

```
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

then in location update callback you:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    // check location
    // get time of sunset

    // schedule UILocalNotification
}
```

just found an article for you: [Setting a reminder using UILocalNotification in iOS 4. Objective-C.](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/setting-a-reminder-using-uilocalnotification-in-ios-4-objective-c/) Also check this: [Executing code in background +schedule alarm on date](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: i have read about background location mode.i tried but not succeeded.can you please post small example on this.i will be be very much thankful to you.and in that case is any effect on battery consumption since app will run continuously in back ground..

Answer (score 0):

[Android Awareness API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/) has [recently announced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/semantic-time-support-now-available-on.html) new features that provide a simple solution for your use-case. The way to achieve what you're trying to do is to create and register a TimeFence specified relative to sunrise/sunset.

For example:

```
// Create TimeFence
AwarenessFence sunriseFence =
    TimeFence.aroundTimeInstant(TimeFence.TIME_INSTANT_SUNRISE,
        0, 5 * ONE_MINUTE_MILLIS);

// Register fence with Awareness.
Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(
    mGoogleApiClient,
    new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
        .addFence("fenceKey", sunriseFence, myPendingIntent)
        .build())
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Fence was successfully registered.");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Fence could not be registered: " + status);
            }
        }
    });
```

You will get callbacks when the fence evaluates to TRUE at sunrise, and when it evaluates back to FALSE at 5-min after sunrise.

Please check [Fence API code snippets](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/fence-api-overview) docs for how to add your custom app logic.