# UILocalnotification for alarm application for more than 30sec

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, repeatingalarm

I am working on Alarm base project in iOS objective c.
I had implemented `UILocalnotification` for alarm when application is in background.
But problem i am facing is sound only plays for 30sec.

How can i increase the time interval for the sound or is there any other way to implement it instead of `UILocalnotification` .

```
  - (IBAction)Alert:(id)sender{

        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        //NSDate *date = [NSDate date];


        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotif.fireDate =[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];
        localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        localNotif.alertBody = @"Emergency";

        localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
        localNotif.soundName = @"police.mp3";
        localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        localNotif.repeatInterval = NSYearCalendarUnit;


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

    }


  Note : mp3 file i am using for UILocalnotification is of more that 60min duration.
```

Please advice.
Thank you

Comment: You would need to split that file into multiple 30s sound files, and make multiple notification

Comment: @Tj3n Thank you for the reply. But my mp3 file is more that 30sec.

Answer (score 1):

If device is in active mode, notification sound only play for 5 seconds. If device is in sleep mode, notification will play 30 seconds sound. I guess, this is standard behavi

As per Apple guidelines, you need to use mp3 file with 30 seconds duration. Please check below link.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationsound

Note: FYI, UILocalNotification is deprecated from iOS10. You need to start using UNUserNotificationCenter.

Comment: Is there any another way to implement the alarm feature other than notification? Because notification only play for 5 or 30 second. Whereas expected result is it should play for more the 60second?

Comment: This is not possible unless you set two local notification. Alarm App of iOS have special privilege to play sound more than 30 seconds. Please check link which might helpful for.you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445090/alarm-clock-app-in-ios